# Kotlin, immutable interface with 2 implementations and generics

Tags: kotlin

I have the following interface:

```
interface Point {
    val name: String
    val position: Position
    fun move(newPosition: Position): Point
}
```

and have two implementations of the `Point` (`Foo` and `Bar`). Function `move` *never* changes the `Point` implementation. In other words, the implementation of the point stays the same, once created.

However, the signature of `move` does not say so. Is there a way to specify the return type in a such way so the return type is the same as the implementation type?

E.g.:

```
class A : Point {
  override fun move(newPosition: Position): Point {
     return A(name, newPosition);
  }
  ...
}
class B : Point {
  override fun move(newPosition: Position): Point {
     return B(name, newPosition);
  }
}
```

and then:

```
var a: Point = A()
...
a = a.move(newPos)
```

(this code requires casting and I want to avoid it).

Comment: provide example of your class `A` implementation

Comment: @IR42 sorry, thought it was clear from the text... Updated.

Comment: Your motivation isn't clear. The point of an interface is to hide implementation. *Any* implementation. `this code requires casting and I want to avoid it` Of course you do, it's ugly to discourage you from using it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do, is use a type parameter:

```
interface Point<T> {
    val name: String
    val position: Position
    fun move(newPosition: Position): T
}

class A(
    override val name: String,
    override val position: Position
) : Point<A> {
    override fun move(newPosition: Position): A {
        return A(name, newPosition);
    }
}
class B(
    override val name: String,
    override val position: Position
) : Point<B> {

    override fun move(newPosition: Position): B {
        return B(name, newPosition);
    }
}

var a: A = A("", Position(2,3))
a = a.move(Position(2,3)
```

Comment: Maybe `<T : Point>`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec just `Point` is a raw type, which is not allowed in kotlin

Comment: `<T : Point<T>>` is the usual way around that.